# How to dynamically delay observable over time

Tags: c#, system.reactive, rx.net

I currently have a feature that users `Timer()` to fire an observable immediately and then every x millseconds after.

```
HoldPayloads = Observable.Merge(
    EnumeratedSymbolKeys.Select(
        o => Observable.FromEventPattern<MouseButtonEventHandler, MouseButtonEventArgs>(
            h => o.PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown += h,
            h => o.PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown -= h)
            .Select(_ => Observable.Timer(DateTimeOffset.Now, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(o.Frequency))
            .TakeUntil(Observable.FromEventPattern<MouseButtonEventHandler, MouseButtonEventArgs>(
                h => o.PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp += h,
                h => o.PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp -= h)))
                .Switch()
                .Select(_ => o.Payload)));
```

What I'd like to have is The observable fire immediately when a button is clicked, then after initial longer delay start to repeat at either a faster interval or a decreasing interval down to a limit, something like this:

```
--x------x--x--x--x--x--x-->
```

or

```
--x------x----x---x--x-x-x->
```

I attempted to use `Delay()` combined with `Scan()` to generate exponentially lower values to delay by but couldn't get it to work. Was I on the right track? Any better ways to do something like this?

Revised code using the answer from Shlomo:

```
HoldPayloads = Observable.Merge(
EnumeratedSymbolKeys.Select(
    o => Observable.FromEventPattern<MouseButtonEventHandler, MouseButtonEventArgs>(
        h => o.PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown += h,
        h => o.PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown -= h)
        .Select(_ => Observable.Generate(
            1,
            q => true,
            i => i+1,
            i => i,
            i => i==1
                ? TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(0)
                : i > 10
                    ? TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(50)
                    : TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500/i))
        .TakeUntil(Observable.FromEventPattern<MouseButtonEventHandler, MouseButtonEventArgs>(
            h => o.PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp += h,
            h => o.PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp -= h)))
            .Switch()
            .Select(_ => o.Payload)));
```

Ended up modifying the conditional so that the first item was immediate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Observable.Generate` is your friend (discussed well on [this](http://www.introtorx.com/Content/v1.0.10621.0/04_CreatingObservableSequences.html#ObservableTimer) page).

For increasingly frequent values, replace `.Select(_ => Observable.Timer(DateTimeOffset.Now, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(o.Frequency))` with something like this:

```
Observable.Generate(
    1, 
    _ => true,
    i => i + 1,
    i => i,
    i => i > 10
        ? TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(50)
        : TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500 / i)
)
```

Whatever your pattern is, fit it into that last parameter. Think of `Generate` as like a reactive for loop with all the dials available to you.

---

**EDIT**:

With the code above, the first item from `Generate` will be delayed. If you want the first item immediately, then the second item delayed, you can do as follows:

```
Observable.Generate(
    1, 
    _ => true,
    i => i + 1,
    i => i,
    i => i > 10
        ? TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(50)
        : TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500 / i)
)            
.StartWith(0)
```

So the original `.Select(_ => Observable.Timer(DateTimeOffset.Now, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(o.Frequency)` is now `.Select(_ => Observable.Generate(...).StartWith(0))`

Comment: Really appreciate the help!

Comment: Also, if you want the immediate item, you could do `Observable.Generate(...).StartWith(0)`.

Comment: I guess I misunderstood your original answer. I basically replaced `Observable.Timer` with `Observable.Generate` inside my select statement (see revised code in question). Was there another way I could've done that. Still trying to wrap my head around all of this.

Answer (score 1):

I just thought I'd just add an answer to help to make the final query more readable. I haven't changed the answer in any way and I'm not looking to have this answer accepted or even up-voted. I just wanted to help add some clarity in how to understand the query.

I've just done a bit of substitution refactoring and have changed the query to be:

```
HoldPayloads =
    EnumeratedSymbolKeys
        .Select(o =>
            MouseDowns(o)
                .Select(_ => Generate().TakeUntil(MouseUps(o)))
                .Switch()
                .Select(_ => o.Payload))
        .Merge();
```

To me this is much easier to read and the intent of the query is very clear.

It just leaves the definition of `MouseDowns`, `MouseUps`, and `Generate`. These are:

```
IObservable<Unit> MouseDowns(EnumeratedSymbolKey o) =>
    Observable
        .FromEventPattern<MouseButtonEventHandler, MouseButtonEventArgs>(
            h => o.PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown += h, h => o.PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown -= h)
        .Select(EncodingProvider => Unit.Default);

IObservable<Unit> MouseUps(EnumeratedSymbolKey o) =>
    Observable
        .FromEventPattern<MouseButtonEventHandler, MouseButtonEventArgs>(
            h => o.PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp += h, h => o.PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp -= h)
        .Select(EncodingProvider => Unit.Default);          

IObservable<int> Generate() =>
    Observable
        .Generate(1, i => true, i => i + 1, i => i,
            i => i == 1
                ? TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(0) 
                : (i > 10 ? TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(50) : TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500 / i)));
```

Now that these are separated out it's easier to confirm that each are correct and hopefully that the whole code is correct.

Comment: Agreed that its much easier to read. I'll give this a shot today. Thanks!